# Is there any way to install PWA from terminal command?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'd like to install PWA from https://carbon.now.sh/ automatically.

It seems chrome has some commands like
https://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/list-useful-google-chrome-command-line-switches/

however, there is no installation of PWA...

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: No. You need to install a valid PWA while in an HTTPS browser. And the user needs to explicitly approve the install with the browser dialogue.

Comment: @MathiasThank you very much.

Comment: I am really looking for it, in localhost you don't need to server your PWA on HTTPS. So it would be a great feature to add a PWA short cut on desktop due installation.

Comment: @Mathias, is it possible to do that from the CLI though?

Comment: @ryuta69, did you learn anything?

Comment: No the only install option is through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch any page using the --app switch.

```
/opt/brave.com/brave/brave --app="https://carbon.now.sh/"
```

> Remember to provide --user-data-dir, profile etc or it will create a default one in some temp dir

> For windows use a windows syntax of course ^^;

This is not the same as installing a PWA though.
This will launch the browser with the page in a full window without adress bar etc... Just remaining the OS window title bar + min/max/close button.

> ⚠️ The manifest file is not used, the window is not special and new windows are open in a new tabbed window

Answer (score -1):

On Edge (Chromium based) for Windows and MacOS you can do this with a [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#webappinstallforcelist). Your question is about Chrome without a specific OS provided, so this doesn't directly answer your question, but this might be considered as an alternative if you don't need Chrome specifically. This could be useful in an Enterprise setting.

Answer (score -4):

You can use Microsoft Edge Site as App functionality to do this, Open any website and then go to the menu (3 dots top-right) then go to apps and select install this site as an app and you are good to go.

Comment: Welcome! Your answer doesn't really answer how to install PWA from the terminal, please watch the question.